# In BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream class ,why Before writing ,read is not good.......?

Tags: io

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class BufferedInputOutputStreamExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        BufferedInputStreamExample bisx=new BufferedInputStreamExample();
        BufferedInputStream bis=bisx.inputMethod();

        BufferedOutputStreamExample bosx=new BufferedOutputStreamExample();
        bosx.outputMethod(bis);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry--------File not exists");
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException   ---:"+io.getMessage());
        }


    }
}
class BufferedInputStreamExample
{
    BufferedInputStream bis=null;
    BufferedInputStream  inputMethod()throws FileNotFoundException,IOException
    {
            FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("C:/e-SDK-4.1-win32-x86_64 (1)/RahulExample/src/Test.java");
            bis=new BufferedInputStream(fin); 
            int c;
            while((c=bis.read())!=-1)
                System.out.print((char)c);
            System.out.println();

        return bis;
    }
}
class BufferedOutputStreamExample
{
    BufferedOutputStream bos=null;
    int outputMethod(BufferedInputStream bis)throws IOException,FileNotFoundException
    {
        bos=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/varun.txt"));

        int c;

        while((c=bis.read())!=-1){
            bos.write(c);
        }
        bis.close();
        bos.close();
        System.out.println("File created.............");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

in this program we read the content from a file by using bufferedinputstream, when i want to write the content of Test.java file in varun.txt file by using bufferedoutputstream,its create file but not write any thing in varun.txt.if we write the content from Test.java to varun.txt without reading it create file and write both.why it is done like this.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `bisx.inputMethod()`, you're reading the stream in order to print its contents.  Thing is, *you don't want to do that just yet*.  Reading the stream consumes it, so the stream you're returning is already at its end, with nothing left to read.

If you want to print out all the contents of the file, and then write it all to the other file, that's two separate operations. Depending on the size of the file, it will require either reading the file twice -- with two different input streams -- or buffering the whole thing in memory.

Instead, if you just want to display the contents of the file as you copy it (which looks like the real goal here), you have a couple of worthwhile options...

- You could **have `outputMethod` print the data** as it's writing to the output file.  This is probably the simplest fix, in the short term.  Of course, you'd also remove the code in `inputMethod` that reads the stream.
- You could **subclass `FilterInputStream` or `FilterOutputStream`** to define a stream that, whenever it reads or writes data (respectively), does something else with it as well.  It could, for example...

  - **print the data to `System.out`.** Very simple, but rigid.  The more i consider it...meh.
  - **copy the data to another *arbitrary* output stream.**  This would be far more flexible; for example, you could send to a log file or something.  And it requires so little extra code over `System.out.print`, that it typically wins in the bang-for-your-buck department.
  - **trigger an event** that other objects can subscribe to.  This could give you nearly unlimited flexibility (as the subscribers are no longer forced to care about streams), but can also be quite a bit more complex.  (You'd basically need to add an event/subscription API.)  It'd typically be overkill for a tiny project like this one.

  Note that if you go this route, you should consider refactoring things so that the objects' constructors take a stream rather than creating one.  That way, `main` can decide whether the output happens and where it goes, and the other objects don't even have to care.  They can just do their job, treating the streams as regular old InputStreams and OutputStreams, and the stream you pass in determines what else happens.

(By the way: In order to concentrate on the main issue, i've semi-ignored the fact that you're "decoding" by casting to `char`.  This may not faithfully reproduce the contents of the file, unless you know for a fact that the contents are ASCII characters.  I assume the output is a debugging thing, so this doesn't deserve a long rant...but know that in the general case, it is likely to cause issues.)